# What is the best HTML template email builder?

Tags: html, email, marketing

I'm looking for a great online tool for building HTML emails templates that has lots of edits and customize functionality control but is easy to use, configure and export - what's your favorite?

So, I need a drag & drop like App, I don't want to touch the code. The App should generate good looking design and should be optimized for the majority of email clients (Outlook also).

I use the Mailchimp now, but it has a very bad design and templates for the newsletter. I want to upload to Mailchimp my custom made newsletter in zip format exported from an email builder.

I short: I need an email template builder without coding knowledge to use.

Comment: It looks like the previous question was accordingly edited an the on-hold weren't removed.

Comment: @Stas the problem on the "on hold" should be addressed at that moment because now there are 2 identical questions.

Comment: @Izzy any reason for keeping the "on hold" on the old question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using the Postcards solution by Designmodo: https://designmodo.com/postcards/

It will allow you exactly what you looking for - building emails online with templates using a drag & drop editor, lot's of customization options and integration with the major clients such as Shipofy, Mailchimp,  Salesforce and etc. You can export freely as well.